# Using JavaScript to search the URL for hash, not a specific string though

Tags: javascript, html, url, if-statement, hash

I'm looking for a way to search the URL of the page, looking for a specific keyword in the has.

For example, if the hash "/three" exists, I want to run a JavaScript function. The problem though, is that I have eight hashes, and they can be triggered in any specific order.

This means that I can't just do something like this -

```
<script>
        window.onhashchange = function(){
  switch(location.hash) {
    case '#hide':
      javascript:alert("Find a valid NFC tag to continue!")
    break;
    case '#hide/one':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number one!")
    break;
    case '#hide/two':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number two!")
    break;
    case '#hide/three':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number three!")
    break;
    case '#hide/four':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number four!")
    break;
    case '#hide/five':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number five!")
    break;
    case '#hide/six':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number six!")
    break;
    case '#hide/seven':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number seven")
    break;
    case '#hide/eight':
      javascript:alert("You found piece number eight!")
    break;
  }
}
        </script>
```

because the URL might end up being "example.com/index.html#hide/one/five/three/etc..". The way that it's configured right now, is that it'll specifically search for "#hide/one", "#hide/two", etc.

But "#hide" isn't inserted with every hash, only with the first. So there will never be a "#hide/one/#hide/two, etc".

I need to figure out how I can search for "one", "two", "three", etc, in the URL and perform functions accordingly.

Thanks in advance, looking forward to learning more on this!

EDIT - Just read through my post and I feel like I should clarify something. You know the JavaScript function "hash.length"? Something like "hash.length" but for contents, like "hash.content" or something would be great. I don't think that exists though.

-Mitchyl

Comment: its a string - use a regex.

Comment: Why not split on the `/` and then iterate over the array elements and check the individual values at each iteration? If you need to have `#hash` at the beginning, just do an indexOf search on the string and verify it's `0`.

Comment: Regex? I've actually never really heard that term before. How would I go about using a regex?

Comment: You've never heard of regular expressions? Go to www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: overload the switch to do a compare each case: switch(true) {  case !!location.hash.match('#hide'): ...

Comment: Split it on `/` and use `indexOf` to search the array.

Comment: Oh god sorry. Of course I've heard of regular expressions. Just didn't click that it would be regex.

Comment: @barmar So split the hashes on the /. So it'd be "/one", "/two", etc? or "/one/", "/two/". Sounds like that could work, though.

Comment: `split` returns an array without the delimiters, so it will be `["hide", "one", "two", "three", ...]`

Comment: I feel really dumb now, but I'm completely lost on this splitting concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hashArray = location.hash.substr(1).split('/'); // substr(1) skips over the # at the beginning
if (hashArray.indexOf('hide') != -1) {
    if (hashArray.indexOf('one') != -1) {
        alert("You found piece number one");
    } else if (hashArray.indexOf('two') != -1) {
        alert("You found piece number two");
    } ...
}
```

BTW, you don't need a label `javascript:` before calls to `alert()`. The only time you need `javascript:` is when you're putting a script in an HTML attribute that normally contains a URL, e.g. `href` and `src` attributes -- it takes the place of something like `http:` to tell it to run the code rather than download a document.

It works in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rbka814x/show/#hide/one). After clicking on the link, edit the URL and change `one` to `two`, you'll get the alert.

Comment: Looks really good, but it doesn't appear to be working. As in, literally nothing happens. No errors in the console, either. Oh, and thanks for the `alert()` tip, I didn't know that!

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to make it so that when I add a new one, for example, if I added "/two" after the "/one", it would say that I added two instead of one again. Currently, if "/one" is already added and I add "/two", it'll say that I found "one" again.

Comment: My function uses `else if`, so it only reports the first one it finds. If you want to report all the matches, use a sequence of `if` statements rather than `else if`.

Comment: Or you could simply iterate through all the elements with a `for` loop, reporting each of them. This is all just basic programming logic.

Comment: Ah, I know it's basic logic. I'm learning a lot through making small projects like this, and it's really fun to be honest. One last question because I feel like I'm stretching this question a little too far. When I change the `else if` to an `if`, each time I change the hash now, it'll list all of them. Like, "You found one". "You found two", etc. Could I have it just so it displays the most recent change?

Comment: Save the old values in another variable. Then test whether the new value is in the old array, and don't alert it.

Answer (score 0):

*This one is more dynamic.*

You just have to change the very first var "aHash" and the rest will be autobuilt.
BTW this is just nessecary to prevent scripts reaction on hash manipulation by the user itself.
Otherwise you could just iterate of the splitted hash string but this would be error-prone.

```
// here goes the configuration
// if you want to change the "keys" here's the right place
// therefor it's better maintainable
var aHash = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

// autobuild an object with values as keys from given array at the top
var oHash = {},
    i     = aHash.length;
// don't forget that iteration usually starts with [0] but if you get the length will be 1 if one element is available
while( i-- )
{
  oHash[ aHash[ i ] ] = null;
}


window.onhashchange = function()
{
  // split hash into pieces into an array
  aHash  = document.location.hash.split('/');
  var iL = aHash.length;

  // workaround for case: '#hide/'
  if (aHash[ iL-1 ] === '')
  {
    --iL;
  }
  if (iL == 1 && aHash[0] === '#hide')
  {
    alert ('Find a valid NFC tag to continue!');
    return;
  }

  // only needed if one wants to collect the result
  var sAlert = '';

  // iterate from left to right in hash
  // if this isn't nessecary one can use the same while structure like at the beginning (without iL)
  i = -1;
  while( ++i < iL )
  {
    if (oHash[ aHash[ i ] ] === null )
    {
      // alert every time
      alert( 'You found piece number ' + aHash[ i ] + '!' );
      // colect for alert
      sAlert += aHash[ i ] + ' and ';
    }
  }
  if (sAlert !== '')
  {
    alert( 'You found pieces number ' + sAlert.substr( 0, sAlert.length-5 ) + '!' );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test that the hash starts with `#hash` and numbers exist in your hash path, then you can try this.

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (location.hash.indexOf('#hash') !== 0) {
        return;
    }

    location.split('/').forEach(function(num) {
        switch (num) {
            case 'one':
                alert("You found piece number one!");
                break;
            // ...
            case 'eight':
                alert("You found piece number eight!");
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this [won't work in IE7 or IE8](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach).

Comment: Hmm. I like this answer, because I don't have to make it work with IE7 or IE8.  I'm kind of confused, because this doesn't work, just like the answer above. I can't see the issue that might be present

Comment: @Mitchyl If you have other libraries or code on the page that might screw with binding a single listener to the `onhashchange` event, then you can use `window.addEventListener('hashchange', myHashChangeFunction, false)`. It's probably better practice, too.